# Error code 409 when using App Service Editor if deployed using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

We recently moved an App Service from one App Service Plan to another.  Now, when we deploy the using Azure DevOps, the App Service Editor returns an error code 409 when we try to edit any files.  Inside of the App Service Editor, I can see all of the published files.  The app also doesn't start.  When trying to deploy to it using Visual Studio, the error code below occurs.  We've deleted the Publish profile and created a new one and yet it continues.  On Devops, we recreated the Release definition and even deleted all of the Service Connections and yet it continues.  I suspect something is wrong with the App Service itself.

Error Web deployment task failed. ((2/7/2019 11:38:02 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)

(2/7/2019 11:38:02 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Offline.htm'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
   at System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings.CreateWriter(String outputFileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AppOfflineRuleHandler.AddAppOfflineFilesToEachApp(DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, Boolean whatIf)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AppOfflineRuleHandler.AddChild(DeploymentSyncContext syncContext, DeploymentObject destinationParentObject, DeploymentObject& sourceObject, Boolean& proceed)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAddChild(DeploymentObject destParent, DeploymentObject sourceObject, Int32 position)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncDirPathChildren(DeploymentObject destRoot, DeploymentObject sourceRoot)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData, Nullable`1 passId, String user, String siteName)
Propensio.ServiceHost.AspNetCore C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets
140

Answer (score 4):

I just had a similar problem when pushing code from Azure DevOps to my WebApp. I wasn't able to edit files and got 409's when trying. I tried changing from WebDeploy (which was set by default) to ZipDeploy in my "Azure App Service Deploy" step. Not sure if this info is still of any interest for you but if someone else lands here it might hopefully help!

[image]

Comment: In the Azure App Service Deploy you need to check the checkbox to get this option to show up.  Still a valid solution!

Comment: Thanks ! That worked for me too, the deploy is slower but really helps in Dev/QA to modify the files